# Change button background color using Xceed ColorPicker

Tags: c#, wpf, color-picker, xceed

How can I change button background color by using Xceed ColorPicker on a click event
[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo4Pz.png)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Xaml code

```
<xceed:ColorPicker x:Name="MyNiceColorPicker"/>
<Button x:Name="MyNiceButton" Click="MyNiceButton_Click"/>
```

And C#

```
private void MyNiceButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyNiceButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(MyNiceColorPicker.SelectedColor ?? (MyNiceButton.Background as SolidColorBrush).Color);
}
```